# Make groups with regular expression like in perl?

Tags: c#, regex

In Perl if I use this regex `/(\w+)\.(\w+)/` on the string `"1A3.25D"`, the global vars `$1` strores `"1A3"` and `$2` stores `"25D"`.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, look at this example:

```
var pattern = @"^\D*(\d+)$";

var result = Regex.Match("Some text 10", pattern);

var num = int.Parse(result.Groups[1].Value); // 10
```

`Group[0]` is the entire match (in this case the entire line because I use `^` and `$`.

If you use `Regex.Replace(...)` you can use `$X` to incorporate the groups as you are used to :-)